# Xunit how to test that a decimal property and string are null

Tags: c#, xunit

I want to be able to write a unit test for when a decimal value is null and the string value is null.

```
private void CompareAsNumbersIfNotEmpty(decimal? actual, string expected)
{
    if (expected == null)
    {

    }else if (expected.Length > 0)
    {
        actual.Value.Should().Be(decimal.Parse(expected));
    }
    else
    {
        actual.Should().Be(decimal.Parse(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues do you have?

Comment: If you what you want is for the test to pass when both values are null change the first if to ```if(expected==null && actual == null)```.

Comment: For most assertion methods expected parameter is the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal cannot be null. But a nullable decimal can be null.

Is the code above a test or is it a function that the test calls?

By using Unit and FluentAssertions like you are. You can use the check `...Should().NotBeNull()` on any nullable type or object.